# Need help saving a game to a user's favorited games

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm receiving an error when trying to associate a saved game to the user that saves it. The error says "cannot read property push of undefined"

The user, and game can be read in the console. I think it may have something to do with the user model during the initial creation of the user, however I can't be sure. I did notice if I try to `console.log(user.favGames)` it will be returned undefined.

I've tried everything I can think of, I've re-written the controller roughly 10 times, to no avail.

user model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const SALT_ROUNDS = 6

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, unique: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    avatar: { type: String },
    favGames: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Game', default: null },
    comments: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment', default: null }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
)

userSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: function(doc, ret) {
    delete ret.password
    return ret
  }
})

userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  const user = this
  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next()
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, SALT_ROUNDS, function(err, hash) {
    if (err) return next()
    user.password = hash
    next()
  })
})

userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(tryPassword, cb) {
  bcrypt.compare(tryPassword, this.password, cb)
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)
```

game model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

let gameSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  boxArtUrl: { type: String, required: true },
  twitchID: { type: String, required: true },
  comments: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Comment"}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Game', gameSchema)
```

game router

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const gamesCtrl = require('../../controllers/gameCtrl')

function isAuthed(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user) return next()
  return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Unauthorized ' })
}

router.get('/')
router.post('/', isAuthed, gamesCtrl.addGame)

module.exports = router
```

game controller

```
const User = require('../models/user')
const Game = require('../models/Game')

function addGame(req, res) {
  Game.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    twitchID: req.body.id,
    boxArtUrl: req.body.box_art_url
  })
    .then(game => {
      User.findById(req.user._id)
        .then(user => {
          console.log(game)
          console.log(user.favGames)
          // user.favGames.push(game)
          // user.save()
        })
        .catch(err =>
          console.log('error when updating user with new game', err)
        )
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('error saving game', err))
}

module.exports = {
  addGame
}
```

the error is flagged in my controller at `user.favGames.push(game)`. Note that when a user creates a profile there are no games associated with their profile. I'm pretty sure I'm calling on the actual data instance of the model, not the model itself. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your favGames (and also comments) must be defined as array in user model like this.

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, unique: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    avatar: { type: String },
    favGames: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Game', default: null }],
    comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment', default: null }]
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
)
```

Also user.save() returns a promise, so you need use then block, or await.

So the addGame function must be like this (I converted the code to async/await)

```
async function addGame(req, res) {
  try {
    let game = await Game.create({
      name: req.body.name,
      twitchID: req.body.id,
      boxArtUrl: req.body.box_art_url
    });

    let user = await User.findById(req.user._id);

    if (user) {
      user.favGames.push(game);
      await user.save();
      res.status(200).send("game and user saved");
    } else {
      console.log("user not found");
      res.status(404).send("user not found");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Err: ", err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
}
```

Comment: the req.user._id is in the middleware so I should be good. I'm using JWTs for authentication. let me try your implementation of the async await. Also you are correct in the user schema, totally overlooked that.

Comment: @SalvatoreArgentieri did it work with User.findById(req.user_id)?

Comment: Hey just was able to sit down and implement your suggestions. It did work with req.user._id. I have it set up so I can just pull the whole user object from the request send to the server (figured it would make things a bit more simple that way). Thank you for your help! to anyone checking out this post I think what fixed it was using the async await method. Thanks again for the assist @SuleymanSah

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a matter of checking to see if it exists:

```
User.findById(req.user._id)
  .then(user => {
    if (!Array.isArray(user.favGames)) {
      user.favGames = [];
    }
    user.favGames.push(game);
    user.save();
  })
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still receiving the same error. It's almost as thought user.favGames is completely non-existant